# How to make robot framework wait till data appears on MySQL table to continue test case execution

Tags: python, mysql, robotframework

My test case modifies a value on a table on MySQL, There is some processing by a running service external to the test case that in 5 to 10 seconds takes the previous value and moves it to another table.

So the following code is from the test case, I want to verify that the service has moved the value to the other table.

```
${Result}=    Select Data From Database  SELECT item_id FROM service_table.items WHERE item_id = "30782";
Expected Result  ${Result}  30782
```

The thing is that the service is quite slow and when the test case runs that script, the value isn't on the table and the test fails, is there a way to make the script wait until the item is on the other table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [DatabaseLibrary](https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html#Check%20If%20Exists%20In%20Database), i'm working a lot with. It offer keyword "Check If Exists In Database" and I think should be aware about long response time.

During my experience i never had problems related long response time, but you know never say never ;)

Comment: Does it work with a database that is on a virtual machine/server? I am using paramiko to access a database on a vm.

Comment: Are you using paramiko as ssh tunnel? anyway it shoult work. I never use ssh for secure sql connection, i prefer enable ssl on mysql server

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a custom keyword to do that. For example, you might write a keyword named 'Wait for database query' that takes a query and a timeout. I don't know if there are any low level functions to do that, but one simple trick might be to use [Wait until keyword succeeds](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds) to keep trying the select statement until it succeeds or it times out.